# Can't send a document via Telegram API on Swift; using Vapor

Tags: swift, linux, telegram-bot, vapor

## **Code**

```
        let handler16 = TGMessageHandler(filters: .regexp(pattern: "^11$")) {update, bot in
            if let id = update.message?.chat.id {
                let chatId: TGChatId = .chat(id)
            //    let file = File(data: "hello", filename: "МЭСК.docx")
                let params: TGSendDocumentParams = .init(chatId: chatId, document: .url("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE46130&format=file"))
                try bot.sendDocument(params: params)
            }
        }
```

## **Error**

> Type: server Description: Response marked as `not Ok`, it seems something wrong with request
> Code: 400
> Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL contentReason:

**How can i save my particular document and send it (if it is big) via Telegram Bot ?**

After that I'm running on linux server, i don't know how to do it correct...

If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this `FileInfo.fileId("file_id")` as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way.